# How to get object from json file in node.js?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

i've been looking for this for quite some time and couldn't really find anything. Most guides/doc assumes i am using same app but this is not a case. So i have made node.js api with test call GET api.raidcore.xyz/items which returns an array as you'd expected:
`Javascript
{"data":[{"_id":"5834551dfa44228b52645f43","itemDesc":"lorem ipsum dolor sit amet","itemName":"test item","__v":0}]}`

Now what i want to do is display jst itemName to make list or whatever.

```
res.on('data', function(data){
 var json = json.parse(data);
 let name = json.itemName;
 console.log(name);
}
```

returns undefined object. if i log data alone, it displays everything ok. So how do i actually select what i want to show?

Comment: JSON.parse(, should be uppercase the json part

Comment: You have a more complex object it seems. json.data[0].itemName

Comment: Do you need to use `json.parse`, isn't it already a json

Comment: @Hosar i have JSON.parse, just didn't bothered to type it in uppercase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data looks like this:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "_id": "5834551dfa44228b52645f43",
      "itemDesc": "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
      "itemName": "test item",
      "__v": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

Your JSON object has one property called `data`.

`data` is an array with one element.

That element is a object with four parameters.

So the values you want are available like this:

```
let data = '{"data":[{"_id":"5834551dfa44228b52645f43","itemDesc":"lorem ipsum dolor sit amet","itemName":"test item","__v":0}]}';
let json = JSON.parse(data);
let name = json.data[0].itemName;
```

Comment: ouch, i thought data is payload that comes within a call and everything inside is an actual body. that works now.. thanks

Answer (score 2):

You are using the same var name for json
    `var json = json.parse(data);`
you should be using a different name i.e. parsedJson or something like that, you should also use JSON.pase if you intend to use the code in a case sensitive OS